# create a list for std::forward from ellipsis (...)

Tags: c++, std, perfect-forwarding

I have a function like the following, which uses one object A to construct another object B, forwarding the B onto another method.

Code:

```
static bool ExecuteScriptFunction(CScriptHost* pHost, const std::wstring& strFunctionName, MList* plResult, const MList* plArgs)
{   
    auto MakeV8 = [&](const MList* pList) -> Local<Value>
    {
        Local<Value> var;
        CreateJSObjectFromCPPObject(pHost->GetIsolate(), pList, var);
        return var;
    }
    Local<Value> value = pHost->InvokeFunction(strFunctionName.c_str(), MakeV8(plArgs));

    // Snip //
}
```

I'd like to overload the function, so that I can pass it a variable amount of `plArgs` to pass to InvokeFunction - with the caveat that I need to do it via MakeV8.

To achieve this, std::forward seems like a likely tool for the job, as it means not relying on the less-modern va_* macros, and generally cleaner code, and also learning a bit about a part of the STL I haven't really needed to use before.

I think such an overload would look like the following, however, I am not sure of the behaviour of what I have written, or whether it achieves what I think it does, or whether it achieves anything at all!?

```
// call a javascript function in V8
template <class... Lists /* = MList*/>
static bool ExecuteScriptFunction(CScriptHost* pHost, const std::wstring& strFunctionName, MList* plResult, const Lists* ...args)
{   
    auto MakeV8 = [&](const MList* pList) -> Local<Value>
    {
        Local<Value> var;
        CreateJSObjectFromCPPObject(pHost->GetIsolate(), pList, var);
        return var;
    };

    // InvokeFunction handily already takes a variable list of Local<Value>s
    // I want to pass a ... of Local<Value>s that is generated from ...args     || || || || ||
    // So far, no squiggly red lines in VS 2015 on this line of code            \/ \/ \/ \/ \/
    Local<Value> value = pHost->InvokeFunction(strFunctionName.c_str(), std::forward<Local<Value>>(MakeV8(args))...);

    // Snip //
}
```

Does the following line of code achieve what I'm asking for?
`Local<Value> value = pHost->InvokeFunction(strFunctionName.c_str(), std::forward<Local<Value>>(MakeV8(args))...);`

Or is there another incantation that will produce the behaviour I require?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I definitely need to figure out how to ask this. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following?

```
Local<Value> value = pHost->InvokeFunction(strFunctionName.c_str(), MakeV8(args)...);
```

The use of `std::forward` is of use only if your arguments are of type `T&&`, which is not the case with your pointers. Search for 'Perfect Forwarding' in case you need more details on that.

In order to expand the variadic argument pack, `std::forward` is not nequired, since the function argument list is already a context in which parameter packs are expanded.

Comment: I will give that a go. I have read that forward is a wrapper to `static_cast<T&&>(t)` and I also read a bit about rvalue references. I have _so_ much reading to do.

Comment: Yes, it is. Whenever you take your arguments as `T&&` (which can be both `T&` and `T&&` depending on the calling context; these kinds of references are usually referred to as 'forwarding' or 'universal' references), `std::forward<T>()` is used to preserve whatever kind of reference it is, when passed to a function.

Comment: ah yes, I also read that Meyer had coined the term, and had talked about the reference deduction stuff. Literally buying the new Effective C++ now! Thanks for clearing that up for me, I think I got myself in a tizz over syntactic sugar

Comment: You're welcome. Consider to up-vote and accept an answer if your problem is solved.

Comment: Forgive me, I was distracted by something else foolish I had done